# Trigger to Check for current record is available and update the current record

Tags: trigger

I've a child object `Dr_Invite__c`, and parent object `Lead`.

My requirement is when i create a record for `Dr_Invite__c`, my trigger will look for the same record is available or not (same record by **fpn id field** ...). 
suppose same record is available with name **X** ,

attach the newly created `Dr_Invite__c` record to respective `Lead` record of **X**.

`Lead` is parent object to all existing `Dr_Invite__c` object record.

I've to write a bulk trigger, I've written a code but it not working as required.

```
trigger ContactAfterInser1t on Dr_Invite__c (before insert, before update) {
    list<Dr_Invite__c> aList = new list<Dr_Invite__c>();

    Set<Id> DrId = new Set<Id>();
    Set<String> EntityId = new Set<String>();
    Set<String> NPISet = new Set<String>();
    Set<String> PECOSID = new Set<String>();
    List<Id>  LeadId= new List<Id>();
    List<Dr_Invite__c>  updaetDrInvite= new List<Dr_Invite__c>();

    for(Dr_Invite__c drIn:trigger.new){
        EntityId.add(drIn.fpn_entity_id__c); 
        NPISet.add(drIn.npi__c);
        PECOSID.add(drIn.pecos_group_pac_id__c);    
    }

    List<Dr_Invite__c> DrinviteList = [
        select id,lead__c,dr_name__c,fpn_entity_id__c,npi__c,pecos_group_pac_id__c 
        from Dr_Invite__c 
        where (fpn_entity_id__c IN :EntityId OR npi__c IN :NPISet OR pecos_group_pac_id__c IN :PECOSID) 
        limit 1];

    if(DrinviteList.size()>0)
    {
        if(trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isupdate)
        {
            for(Dr_Invite__c drIn:trigger.new)
            {   
                for(Dr_Invite__c c:DrinviteList) 
                {    
                    if(c.fpn_entity_id__c==drIn.fpn_entity_id__c || c.npi__c == drin.npi__c || c.pecos_group_pac_id__c==drin.pecos_group_pac_id__c)
                    {
                        drIn.lead__c=c.lead__c;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please check my updated, it does not update field when we create record, but update it when we edit it.

Comment: why dont you move all code base in to before update/create.You dont need any additional dml operation since your trigger is on same object.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use before insert, before update trigger and do not use DML operations.
2. Use map to find appropriate record.

Comment: I want  bulk trigger, so it will be bulk?

Comment: yes, but it is not clear how leads should be assigned to Dr_Invite__c . Is there any field on Lead for matching? Currently it would not work because if we have two Dr_Invite__c records with the same fpn id field and we update one record and this record doesn't have a lead then you are trying to remove leads from all records with the same fpn id field, but this doesn't make sense to me, this logic appears to be wrong

Comment: Please check my updated code.  It does not update field when we create record, but it update field when we edit the record. Please guide